# Switching from dropbox api v1 to v2

Tags: dropbox-api

I'm switching my application which previously used sharpbox (v1 api) to the new .net v2 api.

My app in the developers console of dropbox has no redirect uri set since v1 did not need it.

1) Is it true that in order to use v2 I need to use oauth2 and use a redirect uri.
2) What happens if I add a redirect uri to my existing app in the dev console. Will everyone using my app with the v1 code stop working? So what I'm asking is, does specifying that redirect uri create any changes to people who are using the old version of my app. Will it cease to function?

3) When I push out the new version using v2, I have no problems with forcing my users to re-authenticate to get new authorization tokens. Etc.  Is that all that will be involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Dropbox API v2 does only support OAuth 2, so you will need to use OAuth 2 with it. However, you don't technically need to use a redirect URI. You can use the "code" flow without a redirect URI if that makes sense for your app. You can find more information in [the documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#authorization).

2) Registering a redirect URI on an app does not affect the existing API v1/OAuth 1 functionality.

3) The specifics of migrating an app will depend on the app itself. There are a few things to note though:

- If your app uses the "file type" permission, you'll need to register an new app, as the file type permission is not supported on API v2.
- If you already have OAuth 2 access tokens (API v1 supports both OAuth 1 and OAuth 2) you can use those directly on API v2 without re-authenticating your users (as long as your permission is supported, per the above).
- If you only have OAuth 1 access tokens, you can upgrade those to OAuth 2 programmatically using either [/1/oauth2/token_from_oauth1](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#oa2-from-oa1) or [/2/auth/token/from_oauth1](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#auth-token-from_oauth1) .

Comment: exactly what I wanted to know. Thanks!